# Different behaviour about pthread_cond_wait on OpenBSD and Linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, pthreads

I am testing the following code on both `OpenBSD-current` and `Arch Linux` (the kernel version is `4.18.9`):

```
#include <pthread.h>

int main(void)
{
        pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
        pthread_cond_t cv = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &mutex);
        return 0;
}
```

On `OpenBSD-current`: the program will not exit and block forever, and it conforms to my expection cause no thread signals the main thread:

```
# cc cv_test.c -o cv_test
# ./cv_test
```

But on `Arch Linux`, the program will exit immediately:

```
# cc cv_test.c -o cv_test
# ./cv_test
#
```

After referring the `linux` [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait), the only explanation I can come out is "spurious awake" occured. I run program some times, it will exit immediately every time. How to understand this behaviour? does "spurious awake" occur every time? Or something else?

Comment: Do you check the functions return values to see if they had errors?

Comment: Also, when using pthreads, you need to compile with the `-pthread` option to gcc. That fixes the issue on linux.

Comment: @Shawn You are correct! I tried `gcc` and `clang`, and they both need `-pthread` to fix this problem. It seems a little weird. Could you provide your comment as an answer? And it will be better if you can elaborate why `-pthread` is so important on `Linux`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When compiling multithreaded programs on Linux (And possibly some other OSes), gcc needs to passed `-pthread`, which makes it automatically link with the threading library and do any other important things required to use threads on that particular system.

I'm not certain, but I *think* glibc has dummy thread functions that don't do anything (It certainly has definitions for functions like `pthread_cond_wait()`, at least), which is why code without `-pthread` compiles without a linker error.

When using your code with with a configuration/build system instead of compiling it by hand,  cmake has [FindThreads](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/module/FindThreads.html) to set required compiler flags and libraries in an OS and compiler independent fashion. If using autoconf, the [autoconf macro archive](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/) includes an [ax_pthread](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_pthread.html#ax_pthread) macro that does the same. Other systems probably have their own ways; those are just the two I'm familiar with.